# Is karate-configure.js processed each time a request is made?

Tags: java, karate, cucumber-jvm

I understand that karate-configure.js is processed for each scenario or each example under scenario outlines.
However, I found one interesting thing. In my karate-configure.js, I am generating UUID

[image]

and this traceId is being retrieved and set in Background under a feature file.

[image]

I have a scenario where I am sending two requests, one for post followed by delete. I realized that although the first request takes the header set in Background but the second request doesn't.
So I added a line for header before sending second request:

[image]

To my surprise(although this is desirable), I found out that traceId in second request wasn't the same as the one used by previous request. Does that mean karate-configure.js was processed before sending the second request, even though both are part of one scenario.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you have a [`configure headers`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure-headers) routine *also* in action otherwise this shouldn't happen. Of course it is impossible to tell without seeing all your code.

So if you think you have found a bug in Karate, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I am on older version 0.9.6. Need to check if this is the case in newer version as well. I am not sure how 'configure headers' is different from setting 'headers' and I have not used 'configure headers'. Yeah, with 'configure headers' , you can combine read(), right? Be that as it may, my question was, to have different traceId each time, the line where I set 'config.traceId' in karate-configure.js needs to be run again. And I believe it is processing the karate-configure.js file again. The 'traceId' set as header in post request is different from the one in delete request.

Comment: @pragun my response is "it works for me" :) your move.